# Retornar o maior número em Python com recursividade

Tags: python

Meu professor começou a falar de recursividade, e passou alguns exercícios, só que eu travei em um.

Como diz no enunciado abaixo, devo criar uma função que retorne o maior valor contido em uma lista.

Minha dificuldade é: não estou conseguindo fazer isso usando a recursividade. Minha ideia foi fazer tipo um *bubble sort* e depois só exibir o último elemento, porém, está ocorrendo o seguinte erro:

> RecursionError: maximum recursion depth exceeded in comparison

Não consigo pensar em outra forma de fazer.

*Implemente recursivamente uma função `Max` que retorne o maior valor armazenado em um vetor `V`, contendo `n` números inteiros*

```
global c
global c2
global temp

x = [5, 2, 8, 4, 6, 9, 0, 1]

c = 0
c2 = 1
temp = max(x)

def Max(x):
    global c
    global c2
    if x[c] > x[c2]:
        x[c], x[c2] = x[c2], x[c]
        c += 1
        c2 += 1
    if x[len(x)-1] != temp:
        Max(x)
    return x

print(Max(x))
```

Comment: A sua identação não está correta.  Isso em Python é erro de sintaxe, e torna muito difícil acompanahr suas ideias. Acho que você deve ter identado lina a linha com a barra de espaço para formatar a questão - isso não é necessário. Edite a questão, coleo código cmo está no seu editor, selecione o trecho de código e pressione o botão `{}` para formatar o código aqui, por favor.

Comment: Não sabia disso. Obrigada :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Você deve ter percebido que não é a ideia deste site que as pessoas resolvam o problema pra você - mas podem ser dadas dicas.

No caso de função recursiva, a ideia é sempre:  a função verifica se tem uma resposta trivial - nesse caso seria apenas receber uma lista vazia e um outro parâmetro que seria "candidato ao valor máximo". Já que a lista não tem mais elementos, o candidato ao máximo é o próprio máximo - não tem outros concorrentes- e o valor é retornado.

Se a lista não está vazia, ela vai ter em mãos uma lista com alguns elementos e um candidato ao máximo - ela pode extrair o último elemento da lista (o método `.pop()` faz isso), verificar se esse elemento é maior que o candidato atual - se sim, substitui o candidato. Nesse momento, você tem em mãos uma lista mais curta e um candidato atualizado - e precisa decidir o que retornar para quem chamou a função original (e fazer uso da recursividade). Não vou acabar de descrever tudo - aí o exercício continua com algum desafio.

Outra dica: variáveis globais não são necessárias nesse problema. Sua função recursiva vai precisar de dois parâmetros - a lista e um "candidato a máximo".

Espero que essas dicas te ajudem

Comment: Muito obrigada pelas dicas. Com elas consegui fazer o codigo