# Dado um número qualquer, elabore uma função que realize a soma de seus dígitos utilizando-se da recursividade em python

Tags: python

Dado um número qualquer, elabore uma função que realize a soma de seus dígitos utilizando-se
da recursividade. Então, por exemplo, se for passado o número 1435 como parâmetro, a função
desenvolvida deve retornar o número 13 como resultado em python

Comment: Isto responde à sua pergunta? [Retornar o maior número em Python com recursividade](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/308244/retornar-o-maior-n%c3%bamero-em-python-com-recursividade)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Os números são organizados em classes e ordens.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Para somar recursivamente os algarismos de um numero deve-se descobrir qual é a unidade de primeira classe, a somar em totalizador e remover seu algarismo do número.

Para se descobrir qual é a unidade de um número basta obter o resto de uma divisão por 10.

Par se remover a unidade de um número arredonde para baixo o resultado da divisão desse número por 10. Ref: [`math.floor()`](https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/math.html#math.floor)

```
import math

def somar_algarismos(numero, total=0):
  if numero == 0: return total #Se não tiver mais algarismos para somar retorna o total 

  unidade= numero % 10 # obtém o algarismarmo de primeira ordem da primeira classe
  novo_numero = math.floor(numero / 10) # obtém um número com unidade removida

  return somar_algarismos(novo_numero, total + unidade) #Recursivamente aplica a mesma operação ao novo número obtido com a sua antiga unidade já totalizada.


print(somar_algarismos(135711))
```

Código no Repl.it: https://repl.it/repls/InternalSereneMatch

Comment: Vc tb pode usar `numero // 10`, que já retorna o valor "arredondado", sem precisar usar `floor`: https://docs.python.org/3/glossary.html#term-floor-division

Comment: Solução alternativa (que aceita tb números negativos): https://ideone.com/9EMcip

Comment: @hkotsubo .Eu gosto muito da linguagem python, mas coisas como essa [aqui](https://repl.it/repls/WirelessSeagreenModulus) me deixa apreensivo.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/q/1907565